# Best practice for handling add/edit/delete forms

Tags: forms, zend-framework

i'm a little stuck of how i should approach forms in my zend-application. Right now i'm creating two separate forms for addAction() and editAction() for each object i need. My delete-formular is always the same, i simply change some attributes on those.

What i'm wondering about: What is a best-practice here?

Personally i think it could be better just have Forms like "Object1, Object2" instead of "Object1Add, "Object1Edit, Object2Add, Object2Edit"

The reson i ask is because i clearly need two different forms. Some elements are NOT to get changed at all, so i don't want the user to see them.

A Method could be to $form->removeElement('X') inside the controllers editAction()

Why am i thinking this?
Well simple errors - i may add one field here and forget it in the second form or display fields with tag 'disabled=0' in one form but don't have that query on the other one.

Hope i'm making myself clear enough :)
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect time to use the **Factory Design Pattern**. Don't create the form using the contructor, use factory methods instead. Here is a quick pseudocode layout:

```
static createAdd()
  form = new self()
  call form->initCommon
  call form->initAdd
  return form

static createEdit()
  form = new self()
  call form->initCommon
  call form->initEdit
  return form

initComon()
  add the common+validators elements

initAdd()
  add the elements+validators only used in Add

initEdit()
  add the elements+validators only used in Edit
```

Makes sense?

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. It is nice to know a pattern for this "problem". Thanks for this hint.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you do extend the form class. I'd add functions called `edit` or `add` to your class that does the corresponding logic. This way you keep your form-logic in your form and not in your controller.

Comment: Yeah, i extend Zend_Form and basically assign all stuff within the init() - so i would do functions like edit() and inside those $this->removeElement('x') - in the controller then calling the Class and then $this->view->form = $form->edit() ?  This sounds like a way that i could like a lot, thank you!

Comment: Exactly - however take care about situations where you first call `edit` and `add` afterwards (or the other way around) - you easily can loose elements this way. Another way would be to had a parameter to the constructor indicating the mode (not being able to change it afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

I would exactly do what you said : 1 form with all elements. Then depending on the case, just use `removeElement` method on the form to remove the elements that you don't need.

Comment: Thanks so far, sorta guessed that's the way to go, i was just confusing myself like "why built something that you cut in pieces afterwards".. if no other answers turn up, ill accept yours ;)